# A sensitive 2-dimensional cellular automaton with a blocking word

Tags: co.combinatorics, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics, discrete-dynamical-systems, cellular-automata

I'am a Ph.D student in the domain of discrete dynamical systems. My thesis is about spectral properties of cellular automata in higher dimension.

Kurka gives a classification for one dimensional cellular automara and shows that the following properties are equivalent :

1. CA is almost equicontinuous.
2. CA is not sensitive.
3. CA has a blocking word.

In higher dimension, this classification does not hold and we can have a sensitive 2-dimensional cellular automaton with a blocking word.

I have an example of such cellular automaton but it is a litte complicated. I am looking for a simple example of 2-dimensional CA which is sensitive with a blocking word.

---

I have already read this paper. The authors showed that there CA that are not sensitive nor having equicontinuity points.
But my point is about the relation between sensitivity and blocking word in higher dimension.

We know that if a cellular automaton is not sensitive then it has a blocking word in all dimensions. But the inverse is not true starting from dimension 2 where we can have a cellular automaton which sensitive with a blocking word (not fully blocking juste blocking word)

To be exact, I am asking if there is someone who had already written about that.

Comment: Are you aware of this paper https://hal.science/hal-00339354/document ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are asking for a sensitive CA with a blocking word. The cited paper constructs a non-sensitive CA without equicontinuity points. Can you define "blocking word" for a two-dimensional CA?

Comment: I'm just gonna guess that your definition of blocking word is something like this: an $N$-blocking word is a pattern $P$ such that if you see $P$, you know the $N$-pattern at the origin for all time. Sensitive is precisely the complement of "$N$-blocking patterns exist for all $N$". For one-dimensional CA, sensitive is precisely the complement of "$N$-blocking patterns exist for $N$ the neighborhood size". So maybe you are asking if someone studied sensitive CA in higher dimensions, where $N$-blocking patterns exist up to the neighborhood size.

Comment: I don't recall this being studied per se. It should be
possible to construct CA (along the lines of the undecidability of surjectivity,
i.e. finite snakes; combined with the proof from the paper I cite, i.e. sending signals around a rectangle (maybe they already do this kind of combo)) where there are $N$-blocking patterns whose size is busy beaver
in the neighborhood size, yet the CA is sensitive.

Comment: Yes, It is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: That is what is done in Proposition 4 and Proposition 8 of the above paper: it speaks about sensitivity constant $\epsilon$ but it relates to the $N$ of $N$-blocking words by $\epsilon=2^{-N}$

Comment: Yeah I really should've said "I don't recall if that paper explicitly discusses blocking pattern size, go take a look." (Rather than what I did say, some of which is does not even make much sense.)

Answer (score 2):

[Proposition 4 of this paper](https://hal.science/hal-00339354/document) (mentionned by Ville Salo in the comments) does the following: given a Wang tile set that *does not* tile the plane but tiles a $n\times n$ finite square, it constructs a CA that is sensitive to initial conditions but admits a $n\times n$-blocking word.

I don't know if it qualifies as 'simple' but, if I am correct, this construction gives a 12 states CA of radius 2 which is sensitive and admits a $3\times 3$-blocking word. Optimizing a bit, I also think we can get a 4-states radius 2 CA which is sensitive but has a $1\times 1$-blocking word (by shrinking the $\mathcal{S}$ component of states to just $\{1\}$ and adapting the rule to allow only isolated $1$s in a $\mathcal{L}$ background).

As a consequence of this construction, there is no computable upper-bound (in the raidus and number of states) on the size of the smallest blocking word of a 2D sensitive CA (Proposition 8).